# how to use substring with a file path in c#

Tags: c#, substring

I know this value should be used Substring but i am not sure how to do this in C#. Your given code much appreciated. thanks!

What i want to change this :

```
   "C:\\TFS\\Deployment\\files\\1.0.1.1\\test\\test00.xml"
```

to new value:

```
   "C:\\TFS\\Deployment\\files\\1.0.1.1"
```

Comment: Have you checked the documentation? It's supposed you open and read the page.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/substring)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: do you have to use substring? Path manipulation is usually most easily done with methods designed for paths (see D.R.'s answer for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's hard to determine what criteria is used to truncate the string. Besides D.R.'s answer:

```
"C:\\TFS\\Deployment\\files\\1.0.1.1\\test\\test00.xml".Substring(0,31);
```

Comment: @user1358072 I'm quite shocked that this is what you were looking for. This is the result of reading the documentation and counting characters. And counting the characters should not be the criteria of choice when it comes to split strings...

Answer (score 11):

```
var testPath = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(path);
var newValue = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(testPath);
```